# C - struct with a function pointer, how to fix "variable number of arguments" warning?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, arguments

I'm trying to get rid of `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]` while adding `func2` in this simplified example of dealing with a huge open source C library - which has a lot of functions like `func1` and defines like `str1.func = func1;`. Is it possible to fix this warning without modifying func1 or writing something specific for each function / its' defines?

This code at OnlineGDB - https://onlinegdb.com/ry5rNlvDG , click "Fork this" to modify

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1(int a) { // please don't change
    printf("%i\n", a);
}

void func2(int a, char c) {
    printf("%i - %c\n", a, c);
}

struct bigstruct {
    // void (*func) (int a); // old way
    void (*func) (int a, char c); // ??? - some magic needed
};

int main()
{ 
    struct bigstruct str1, str2;

    str1.func = func1; // please don't change
    // ^^^ gives a warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    str2.func = func2;

    error; // onlinegdb - error on purpose to see the warnings
}
```

**UPDATE:** eventually I figured out this is indeed impossible, but I got away from this situation just by adding a new field to the structure that has been passed around through this open source library from one function to another, and as result didn't have to add a new argument to the function. I'm giving top answer to "@Rarity" for his best attempt

Comment: Those functions don't have compatible types. How would you even use `bigstruct.func` if the function it points to could take one or two arguments?

Comment: Is teher any char value which is never used by the `func2`?

Comment: @Mat : I hope that its' possible to use a multiple define like `void (*func) (int a); void (*func) (int a, char c);` or maybe something like `void (*func) (int a, ...)` ?

Comment: @MikeBanon you can use union of several function pointers `union { type1 f1; type2 f2; } func;`

Comment: @coderredoc : no, all the arguments are used by each function. I've thought to embed that "char c" as the upper byte of "int a" if it is unused, but thats not a good way

Comment: @MikeBanon.: Was thinking of wrapping `func1` within a `func3` having the same signature as others...

Comment: @coderredoc : if I do that I'd have to change a lot of defines like `str.func = func1;` --> `str.func = func3;` in many places

Comment: @user7231 : in the case of union there would be many modifications to the `str.func = func1;` defines, like `str.u.f1 = func1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get your concern, if it's warning you're after, then `-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types` is probably ok.

Else, if you want to suppress warnings selectively, then change func declaration to:

```
struct bigstruct {
    void (*func) ();
};
```

, then func will accept various function pointers. Type `void ()()` in C is  "function which takes unknown number of unknown arguments (and returns nothing)", unlike `void()(void)` which is "a function that takes no arguments".

Comment: Plese note C11 6.11 Future language directions: "*6.11.6 Function declarators
1 The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter
type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.*"

Comment: @Rarity: eventually I figured out this is indeed impossible, but I got away from this situation just by adding a new field to the structure that has been passed around through this open source library from one function to another, and as result didn't have to add a new argument to the function. I'm giving top answer to you for your best attempt

Answer (score 0):

With your "please don't change"s it is not possible. However, you could make a cast:

```
str1.func = (void(*)(int, char))func1;
```

The function will be called with 2 parameters but it takes only one. On Intel and VC the second parameter will be ignored. (Parameters are pushed right-to-left onto the stack and `func1` will only access the first parameter and will be unaware of any other parameters higher on the stack). This could be different on other architectures.

Comment: Huhu, this heavily smells like UB.

Comment: @alk, works like a charm as long as prms are pushed R2L, so probably not portable to quantum machines and the like. (I already stopped assuming pushing R2L implies evaluation R2L, which worked like a charm in the 80's.) :-)

Comment: C11 6.3.2.3p8: "*A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted
pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
the behavior is undefined.*"

Comment: @alk, however, as long as prms are passed on the stack and are pushed R2L, the behavior of any compiler will be deterministic and as I described.

Comment: That's way more limited than "VC in Intel". More like VC on Intel x86 (32bit) with default calling convention. UB anyway.